# La question est « pourquoi », et pas « quelles sont les alternatives » — The question is “why”, not "what are available alternatives”

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Suite à la question [Pourquoi « comment vous appelez-vous », et pas « quel est votre nom » comme en anglais ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/330/pourquoi-comment-vous-appelez-vous-et-pas-quel-est-votre-nom-comme-en-a) :

> Dans la plupart des langues, l'équivalent est du type « *What is your name?* », et pas « *How do you call yourself?* ». Cet usage a-t-il des raisons socio-historiques ?

- Alenanno répond « *je n'ai rien trouvé qui pourrait expliquer l'histoire de l'usage de cette expression* »
- Ilya Birman : « *There are different traditions* », et obtient un *upvote* douteux¹ de ma part
- Joubarc : « [...] *doesn't really mean* [...] », « [...] *it's rather widely used* [...] »
- cl-r : « [...] *Bien sûr tout ceci est subjectif, et dépend de l'intonation et de la situation.* [...] »
- Et enfin NNzz le nouveau-bienvenu : « *English language used to have the verb* [...] »

Je n'ai même pas l'impression de complètement dénaturer les réponses. Il me semble que les réponses s'éloignent de plus en plus de la question, et qu'au fond *personne n'y répond vraiment* (« je ne sais pas » est une réponse honnête mais discutable, sur le fond).

Est-ce que je suis le seul à avoir ce sentiment ? Est-ce une bonne initiative de drapaler le tout ?

–
<sup>1. Essentiellement parce que j'étais en manque de cyrillique.</sup>

---

About the question [Pourquoi « comment vous appelez-vous », et pas « quel est votre nom » comme en anglais ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/330/pourquoi-comment-vous-appelez-vous-et-pas-quel-est-votre-nom-comme-en-a) :

> *Dans la plupart des langues, l'équivalent est du type* « What is your name? », *et pas* « How do you call yourself? ». *Cet usage a-t-il des raisons socio-historiques ?*

- Alenanno answers “*je n'ai rien trouvé qui pourrait expliquer l'histoire de l'usage de cette expression*”
- Ilya Birman: “*There are different traditions*”, and gains a questionable¹ upvote from me
- Joubarc: “[...] *doesn't really mean* [...]", "[...] *it's rather widely used* [...]”
- cl-r: “[...] *Bien sûr tout ceci est subjectif, et dépend de l'intonation et de la situation.* [...]”
- And finally newly-welcomed NNzz: “*English language used to have the verb* [...]”

I don't even feel like I'm really changing the nature of the answers. It seems to me that the answers stray more and more away from the question and that, after all, *no one really answers it* (“I don't know” is an honest but questionable in its content).

Am I the only one to feel this way? Is it wise to flag it all?

–
<sup>1. Essentially because I was in need of Cyrillic.</sup>

Comment: À moi, il me semble que les réponses ne font qu'ajouter à la liste des façons de dire « comment tu t'appelles », et répondent à « comment peut-on le dire d'autre que “…” », au lieu d'expliquer pourquoi c'est ainsi plutôt qu'autrement, comme demandé dans la question. Visiblement, ça ne convainc pas grand monde. Bon.

Comment: *Comment d'autre* est un régionalisme ? J'en trouve mention nulle part.

Comment: C'est une très mauvaise habitude de laisser des notes de pied de page sans laisser au lecteur une indication de ce qu'elles contiennent. À quoi peuvent-elles bien servir dans ce cas, à part à perturber l'ordre de lecture ? Je me suis permis de modifier.

Comment: … ah ! Euh… je ne me suis jamais posé la question, pour être franc. Je n'ai aucune idée d'où j'ai pu trouver ça, mais ça m'a toujours semblé naturel pour dire « de quelle autre façon(s) » en plus court… Idk. À part pour l'angoisse existentielle de savoir s'il y en a beaucoup d'autres, comme ça, que je sors complètement de mon chapeau, merci d'avoir posé la question, je ne m'en serais jamais douté sinon. *C'est malin, je suis embarrassé, maintenant.*

Comment: « Comment peut-on le dire autrement », ou « comment peut-on le dire d'une autre façon » respectent la structure originelle, et seront compris par tout le monde (enfin je pense :-)).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, there are some questions for which nobody could find an answer. In these cases, answering with one's findings and concluding that this question is still open is an answer, so there is no point to flag it.

Regarding the quality of the answer, as usual, the score is our way to determine it, so if it has a good score it is a good answer. And as long as there is no answer to this question an answer that says “there is no consensus” is the best we can do. If it goes further and address an issue in the question itself (as Alenanno's does) it will probably get my vote.

So in my opinion there is nothing wrong with this question and its answers.

Answer (score 2):

Non tu n'es pas le seul, je pense comme toi.

StackExchange dérive de stackoverflow, ou le système était logique : une réponse résout le problème et te débloque, elle est acceptée, point.

Le problème c'est que ce système ne s'adapte pas forcément très bien aux autres domaines. Puzzle s'en sorts très bien, mais d'autres sont moins bien lotis, surtout quand le thème même de la communauté pousse à poser des questions qui n'ont pas forcément de réponse objective, unique et définitives.

On a beaucoup de "*j'ai remarqué qu'on dit comme ci dans telles situations et comme ça dans d'autres, vous pouvez confirmer ?*" Et là un natif peut au mieux dire "*ça ça me semble correct, ça ça se dit pas*" mais c'est tout. C'est extrêmement difficile de trancher, et au "mieux" la réponse est oui ou non.

Là même ta question c'est plus pour inciter à la réflexion et au débat que pour avoir quelqu'un qui te répond de façon juste oui ou non.

Je pense qu'il faut se débrouiller comme on peut avec le format du site, mais c'est mon avis.

Donc non tu n'es pas le seul et non je ne pense pas que ce soit une bonne initiative de "drapaler" le tout (j'adore ce mot).